# RuntimeException - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my app I'm trying to read data from a table in my DB, which is created as follows:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createDreamTable = String.format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s" +
            "( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "%s VARCHAR, " +
            "%s TEXT);",
            DreamContract.Dream.DREAM_TABLE_NAME,
            DreamContract.Dream._ID,
            DreamContract.Dream.COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_TITLE,
            DreamContract.Dream.COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_CONTENT);
    Log.d("avirankatz", createDreamTable);
    db.execSQL(createDreamTable);
}
```

When I try to get data from DB using `GetDreamTitles`, as seen below, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`

```
public Cursor getDreamTitles() {
    return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s", DreamContract.Dream.COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_TITLE, DreamContract.Dream.DREAM_TABLE_NAME), null);
}
```

**EDIT:**

`DreamContract.Dream`:

```
public static abstract class Dream implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String DREAM_TABLE_NAME = "dreamDiary";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_CONTENT = "dreamContent";
}
```

Comment: Please, attach constants from `DreamContract.Dream` as well

Comment: I don't believe that line is throwing that `Exception`. It sounds like your using a `CursorAdapter` which expects a column `_id` in the `Cursor`. If that's the case, you need to include the `_id` column in your `SELECT` query projection.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't want to show `_id` value. How can I include it in `SELECT` without viewing it?

Comment: You don't have to display it. It just needs to be in the `Cursor`. You choose which values to show in the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your primary key `_id` in your query like this

```
getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
    String.format(
        "SELECT %s, %s FROM %s", 
        DreamContract.Dream._ID, 
        DreamContract.Dream.COLUMN_NAME_DREAM_TITLE, 
        DreamContract.Dream.DREAM_TABLE_NAME
    ), 
    null
);
```